# PHP: Read a file in the cache of Safari (iOS)

Tags: php, caching, mobile-safari

I have a web application "A" which generates config files for another application "B".
I must be able to transfer this config files by a FTP connection.

"A" and "B" are not on the same network so I have to store the config files made by "A" on my local device (a tablet).
"A" is used with multiple devices. With the iPad (no classical file system) I can't download and store the config files and then upload them to "B".

So I store the config files in the cache of safari and I am able to display them on the tablet even when I am not connected to the network of "A" (with a href of the url in cache).
However when I try to do a "fopen" in the php code with this same url I get this message "failed to open stream: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it."

I don't understand why I'm able to display a file that I can't open in the code ...

Thanks !

Comment: Like you said, it's in the cache of Safari, not in PHP's cache...

Comment: Ok but if I have to different web apps (with two different apache servers in two different networks), how could I share the php's cache ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP only has access to the filesystem on the server, not on the device (PHP itself does not execute on the device, it only produces output *for* a device, by the time the device "gets" it, PHP is finished executing). The reason you are getting the connection refused error is the same reason you need a man-in-the-middle in the first place; A cannot talk to B.

Depending on how much control you have over some of these things, here are my ideas:

1. re-evaluate if you *can* get these machines to talk to each other; get creative
2. If you have control over the output of A, have it generate an HTML , which is submittable to the B server
3. Can you install the web-app which is A on the B server?
4. If you only have one or a handful of such "transfer devices" (and if you are so inclined), consider building a very simple iOS app (you'll start to learn a cool new skill; and a single purpose app like this could be pretty simple)

Comment: 1.Not possible because of security reasons (and I can't change this policy)      2.I tought to this solution and I believe it is the best (Is it possible to transmit the whole file via a get form or I need to convert the config file in html ?)      3.I can but the users must be able to use "A" on the other network       4.I already know Xcode and co. but I can't consider native solution for other reasons        Thank you very much !

Comment: So, as far as number 2, I would put the entire config file contents into a <textarea>, as-is (assuming there aren't any totally strange characters or XML in there (in which case perhaps encoding entities first (and then decoding them on B)